# Use apache upload_tmp_dir for pear applications

Tags: apache-2.2, upload, pear, open-basedir

Is it possible to use upload_tmp_dir parameter defined in the apache configuration for using in PEAR applications?

The real problem appears because of System.php file of PEAR use /tmp directory, but apache has open_basedir restrictions, that doesn't allow to open files located out of these pathes.

And meanwhile, I have several websites on the server with different upload_tmp_dir and different open_basedir restrictions.